# Facebook Messenger bot using Spring Boot?

Tags: java, chatbot, messenger

Nowadays more and more chat bots are being created, as the process is relatively easy if you activate a facebook developer account, and create a facebook page for this purpose.

Probably the **most popular method is to using NodeJS - Heroku**, as it is explained in the following article:

https://chatbotslife.com/how-to-make-a-facebook-messenger-chat-bot-in-1hr-af6bec5e7aec#.xqgu2lb46

After a research I found that making connection with facebook IS possible via Spring boot (as explained here: https://spring.io/guides/gs/accessing-facebook/ ) but I have not found any information or - even similar to the NodeJS - method to handle a messenger conversation using a Spring Boot server.

**Is it possible to request and send facebook messenger messages from Spring Boot?** I would prefer that over NodeJS, as I have a system already built in Spring Boot, and it would be much easier to integrate this feature there, than creating a new service, which would be then connected to the existing one. (even if in some cases I definitely would stuck with the 'microservice' structure.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is possible.

Cast a glance onto that project:

https://github.com/messenger4j/messenger4j-spring-boot-quickstart-template

Though I understand your reason why you want to 'keep things together', I definitely would recommend to separate things to smaller pieces when you can, as it is a much better strategy generally.

Comment: I've been trying to use it. The project runs but webhook doesn't recognize it and throws 502 error. Any idea what could be the problem? Everything is fine with other projects.